# Mysql database backup by using query

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I wanna dump file for MySQL database using query.I got the dump file when i used shell.but i could not get dump file while using heidisql.

**In Shell:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin>
mysqldump -uroot -proot >"D:\backups\student.sql"
```

**In Heidisql:**

1. C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqldump -u root -p root databases student >"D:\student.sql"
2. mysqldump -u root -p[root] [student] > D:/student.sql

Comment: And the error is . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqldump is an application, HeidiSQL is another one. You're creating an .sql file by telling an application to create it, either mysqldump *or* HeidiSQL. You cannot use both applications at the same time.

In HeidiSQL, click on *Tools* > *Export database as SQL*, then follow the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can accept the answer as the correct one by clicking on the marker on the left of it. That's how that works here on StackOverflow.